# Sheets: Calculate this expression for each row in range. How to do it?

Tags: google-sheets

Assume I want to calculate the weighted value of "value 2"  based on the total of "value" if an indicator = 'Y' , how to do this without adding an extra column?

So essentially I want to know how I can apply an expression for each row in a certain range ("artificial column") which I can then apply e.g. a SUM on.

In the screenshot below, how can I calculate the Red Formula without adding an extra column?

[image: screen shot of sample data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=sum(arrayformula(A2:A4*C2:C4*(B2:B4="Y")))
```